# PyRanges: drop specific record from an object

Tags: python, pyranges

Given a specific `PyRanges` object, such as

```py
import pyranges as pr
gr = pr.from_dict({"Chromosome": [1, 1, 1, 1], "Start": [1, 25000, 30000, 40000],
                   "End": [24000, 29500, 37000, 45000], "ratio": [0.5, 0.3, 0.5, 0.4],
                   "ID": (0,1,2,3), "Strand": "+"})

gr

+--------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-----------+--------------+
|   Chromosome |     Start |       End |       ratio |        ID | Strand       |
|   (category) |   (int64) |   (int64) |   (float64) |   (int64) | (category)   |
|--------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-----------+--------------|
|            1 |         1 |     24000 |         0.5 |         0 | +            |
|            1 |     25000 |     29500 |         0.3 |         1 | +            |
|            1 |     30000 |     37000 |         0.5 |         2 | +            |
|            1 |     40000 |     45000 |         0.4 |         3 | +            |
+--------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-----------+--------------+
```

I want to get rid of one interval here (not necessarily the first or the last: for this exercise, for example the third one, *without* relying on the presence of the `ID` column.  So I would need to drop the record with `Chromosome` 1, `Start` 30000 and `End` 37000. The use case is that I need to replace it with a different record.

Replacement of the record is somewhat expensive but not a problem (`pr.concat` followed by a sort to put everything in order), but I can't figure, after reading docstrings and searching around, how to *remove* a record.

I can only think of making the record I want to drop a second `PyRanges` object then using `overlap()` with `invert=True` to remove the record. Is there a more elegant and less convoluted way to do this?